# Why is this loose stone in the Abandoned Refuge glowing?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

In the Abandoned Refuge, there is a loose rock next to a set of double iron doors at coordinates X: -596 Y: 423. The rock is glowing blue with a white light coming out. If I try to interact with the rock it says it can't be added to my inventory.

Why is this loose rock glowing? Is there something significant about it?

[image]

Comment: Can you move it (click & drag)? Might need someone with high strength selected

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't think anyone in my party has enough strength to move the rock.

Comment: If you go back to camp you can temporarily swap out for Lae'zel or Karlach

Comment: There are more stones like this, for example in front of the doors to the Goblin hideout. My guess is there might be something hidden underneath it, but not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This glow is what you get when one of your characters manages a perception check - something is up with this rock! I vaguely recall this one at the bottom of a climb:

> It is nothing important, just a little extra loot.

Some objects in the game can be moved to reveal more interesting things underneath them. You can drag & drop the object to a nearby location or have a character toss it - strength stat might matter. Higher tier spells like Telekinesis probably work too.

If you have no strong enough character in the party you could gamble and try something like a potion of giant strength, hoping whatever is underneath the rock is more valuable than the potion itself.